# Dynamic update of struct field inside mapping

Tags: mapping, struct, solidity-0.8.x, dynamic-call

I have a struct

```
struct Shots{
    uint coverDrive;
    uint straightDrive;
    uint pull;
    uint squareCut;
}
```

and I used a mapping

```
mapping(address => Shots) public BattingSkill;
```

Now I want to write a function which update the value of field in the struct, but the field name is dynamic, Something like this

```
function skillup_Batting(string memory skill_name) public view returns(Shots memory){
    Shots memory skill = BattingSkill[msg.sender];
    skill[skill_name] += 10;
}
```

Whatever skillname is provided we will update only that field and the other field remain same.
Is it possible to code something like this in solidity?

Answer (score 0):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract StackExchange {
    struct Shots{
        uint coverDrive;
        uint straightDrive;
        uint pull;
        uint squareCut;
    }
    mapping(address => Shots) public BattingSkill;

    function incrementShot(string memory shot, uint value) public {
    require(value > 0, "Value must be greater than zero.");
    require(
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("coverDrive")) ||
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("straightDrive")) ||
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("pull")) ||
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("squareCut")),
        "Invalid shot type."
    );
    Shots storage myShots = BattingSkill[msg.sender];
    if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("coverDrive"))) {
        myShots.coverDrive += value;
    } else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("straightDrive"))) {
        myShots.straightDrive += value;
    } else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("pull"))) {
        myShots.pull += value;
    } else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(shot)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("squareCut"))) {
        myShots.squareCut += value;
    }
}
}
```

This will work .